# Cross Platform (XP, Vista and 7) file browser. Windows explorer.exe

Tags: windows-explorer

I am very naive when it comes to this. I am however looking for a file browser program just like Windows explorer.exe that can be used on Windows XP, Vista and 7. If there is a version of explorer.exe that works in all 3 platforms that would be best, but if there is something else I could use that would be ok too. Can anyone point me in the right direction in this regard.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "just like Windows explorer"? Should the program look like Windows Explorer?
If not, the [Free Commander](http://www.freecommander.com/) is a very useful file browser (like Total Commander, but free).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Cubic Explorer](http://www.cubicreality.com/ce/download/):

> CubicExplorer is a file manager aimed for basic and advanced users.
>   Its key features are tabs and bookmarks. It also has sessions,
>   filtering, file previews, search and many more features. First version
>   was released in 2006 and it remains to be under active development.
>   Currently it’s a Windows only application but there are plans for
>   cross-platform support.

[image]